# Unable to rename column in R

Tags: r

The first column in my data frame is greyed out. It seems to have no name. I need to name it so that I can subset the data frame based upon values in that column.

[image: Here is a screenshoot]

I tried naming it using `colnames` as follows:

```
colnames(copernicus_test)[1] <- "Star ID"
```

However this renamed column V1. As you may have guessed, the data frame was just transposed, so I imagine this has may explain why the column is greyed out.

Of course, I have the un-transposed data stored as a list.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. `copernicus_test <- mtcars; colnames(copernicus_test)[1] <- "Star ID"; View(copernicus_test)` -> works. The first "column" is no column, it's the row names.

Comment: As luke said, that is not a column, it is the names of the rows. You can use `copernicus_test["Star ID"] <- row.names(copernicus_test)`

Comment: Hi @PierreLafortune I tried your command but it on re-Viewing the data frame it has not done anything ;-/

Comment: hi @lukeA it seems likely that some command I ran has done something unusual with the data. The data originally came in the .fits format, and has been cleaned up extensively. I'm not sure how to post a replica.

Comment: Are you sure that you're dealing with a data frame, and not with a matrix? In other words, what is the output of `class(copernicus_text)`?

Comment: hi @RHertel the output is `data.frame`

Comment: OK. Thanks. In this case I have nothing to add to what @lukeA and @ PierreLafortune have already stated. Attempting to rename individual columns of a matrix could have been a problem, but for a data.frame things should be alright if this is a "real" column.

Answer (score 2):

To demonstrate with a reproducible example:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:4, y=LETTERS[1:4], row.names=month.abb[1:4])
df
#     x y
# Jan 1 A
# Feb 2 B
# Mar 3 C
# Apr 4 D
```

The 'first column' is really just the row names. To use it as a column we create the new column and assign the row names to it:

```
df['Star ID'] <- row.names(df)
df
#     x y Star ID
# Jan 1 A     Jan
# Feb 2 B     Feb
# Mar 3 C     Mar
# Apr 4 D     Apr
```

Now we have a new column called `Star ID` to use for operations. To eliminate the original row names, run `row.names(df) <- NULL` after.

*Side Note:* Try not to name columns with spaces, it creates a potential headache later on.